# Guidance on setting the AggregateQueryLimit Deployment Property on the CONFIG db

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

The default value for AggregateQueryLimit on a CRM installation is 50,000
 A lot of people have hit the "Aggregate Query limit exceeded" when performing aggregate operations such as COUNT using fetchxml when the entity being queried has more than 50K records for performing an aggregate operation using the SDK(from an external app) and/or using CRM graphs
 I have seen solutions ranging from updating the DeploymentProperties table to using the UpdateAdvancedSettingsRequest to up this number.
 What I haven't seen anybody talk about is real world performance impact (if any) caused by this change.
 Can anyone from the Product team and/or anyone who has upped this setting in a real world enterprise grade production deployment comment on the ramifications of increasing the value of this setting to say 100,000,000

Answer (score 1):

A hundred million might be a bit much. [Paul Way says on his blog](http://paul-way.com/crm-2013-aggregate-query-record-limit-exceeded/) that you should easily be able to increase this to about a quarter million or so, but a hundred million seems a bit out of scope for CRM as a product. I've never needed more than 250,000 records in a single group (though I have gotten close with a couple of sparsely-filtered queries); you can probably push that to 500,000 with a competent DBA managing the server, but a two-thousand-fold increase over the default limit is IMO going to be too much to ask.